# Which field does f belong to?

Tags: real-analysis

f is discontinuous on a subset of R, which one is impossible?

A. empty set B. Rational numbers C. Irrational numbers D. Positive real numbers E. Real numbers

I cannot rule out the wrong answers. Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $f$ defined on all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: You should be able to rule out one of the answers instantly, and you have almost certainly seen an example of a function that rules out (E). Once you have that example, a pretty straightforward modification of it rules out a third answer, leaving you with just two candidates; with that much of a pointer, can you find them?

Answer (score 1):

f cannot be discontinuous on all the Irrationals ( if it is continuous at all the Rationals); the set of points of continuity of a real valued function of a real variables must be a $G_{\delta}$ set, and the Irrationals are not a $G_{\delta}$ ; by Baire Category and by the fact that the Rationals are not a $G_{\delta}$ as the union of countably-many singletons.

The general result is that the set of points of continuity for $f: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a $G_{\delta} $ ; this follows by using the concept of the oscillation of a function at a point.